# Sending data from backend to frontend public Javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend

I want to send data from my backend to the frontend public javascript file. I am aware of using ejs, but I have a dedicated javascript file and I want to send data to that file.

Here is my backend nodejs code:

```
router.get('/', isAuth, function (req, res) {
User.find({ id: req.user[0].id }).populate("tweets").populate("tags").exec(function (err, user) {
    res.render("dashboard", {user: user});
    // res.send(user);
});
});
```

Here is how I am calling the script file from the dashboard.ejs just before end of body tag:

```
<script src="/dashboard/scripts/script.js"></script>
```

And this is where I want the data that I sent from the backend to be stored.

```
const ext = data_from_backend
```

I have been trying a lot, but not able to found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the core of the problem but also took help from answers here. Here is what I did. I first converted the object to a string using `JSON.stringfy()` and then sent it to the front-end script and then convert it again using `JSON.parse()`. But, I was getting `JSON code 'T'` error because of '/' (slashes) in my embed code, hence I had to change the embed code to something else that was taken care of in the front-end script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting your object to a string and then passing it to the script tag.
Then you can parse that string, convert it to and object and then store it as a global variable.
Other script tags should be able to access global variables.

Change your node js file to:

```
res.render("dashboard", {user: JSON.stringify(user)});
```

In your .ejs file add a script tag before your `<script src="/dashboard/scripts/script.js"></script>`:

```
<script>
    const str = "<%= name %>";
    const obj = str.replace(/&#34;/gi, '\'');
</script>
```

Now you can use obj inside other script tags

```
<script>alert(obj);</script>
```

Comment: It works, but now it is treating it as a string. Also, can you tell me what this here does? ```str.replace(/&#34;/gi, '\'')```

Comment: Ejs, stringify convert all the quotes ' to /&#34 so you have to convert them back. Use JSON.parse(obj) to convert string to object